# Angular 2 Project into real world, into my domain. How?

Tags: angular

how can I use my project in my domain at godaddy host. If I upload all the folders, will that work ?

If I use, html/css/javascript/php, when I upload all files, that works but how to do it with angular2?

I am suspicious because i use command prompt (npm start) to start the angular 2 project in localhost otherwise it does not work.

Comment: When you publish code to server It will work

Comment: then do u know how to upload folders to godaddy? :D it is hard as hell since there are so many  folders and node-module files inside. Godaddy only let upload files not folders

Comment: I dont know how to upload but if you upload all files It will work @cihangirND

Comment: thanks you give me hope. even if it takes hours, i will do it

Comment: so godaddy server does what 'npm start' do by itself, right ?

Comment: :) No, Angular 2 just need a web server like IIS etc. When you publish code to webserver It will work

Comment: What you need is webpack for instance, to bundle all your dependencies into one JS file.

Comment: can u suggest webpack ?